# How to keep 3 image silders on the same row in wordpress

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have three short codes listed on my page and they dont stay on the same line. What is a vary simple way of controling the images into 3 per line? I have a CSS plugin which will let me use DIV tages to assign a DIV that will control the allignment. I read alot of answers relating to this but I do not know enough about coding to correctly apply each technique. Please help. A video source would be great!

Comment: you're going to need to give more information, either a screen shot, some code, or a link

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit unclear, but if the images are in a DIV and you want to align them horizontally instead of vertically, you could use something like:

```
#idofthediv img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; //not necessary, but it's likely you'll want to do this
}
```

Hopefully this helps.